# How can I set Style properties on a column in an XAML datagrid using Powershell?

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell

I am building a WPF UI using Powershell and XAML. The particular feature I am having problems with is setting the style on the columns. I am able to set the style within the XAML, but there are 9 columns (3 columns each in 3 data grids) so I feel it would be neater to set the properties in the code rather than repeat the same block 9 times.

This is how I set the style on a single column through XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Attribute" Binding="{Binding Attribute}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

This sets blank cells to light green. However, my preferred method would be to set this in Powershell.

So far I have figured out how to manually create the columns in Powershell if they are not explicitly added in XAML. I do this like so (after binding to the controls):

```
$arrAllDataGrids = @($dataGridUser, $dataGridHome, $dataGridWWID)
ForEach ($objDataGrid in $arrAllDataGrids)
{
    $objDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = $false
    $colAttribute = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn -Property @{"Header" = "Attribute"; "Binding" = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding "Attribute"}
    $colValue = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn -Property @{"Header" = "Value"; "Binding" = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding "Value"}
    $colDate = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn -Property @{"Header" = "Date"; "Binding" = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding "Date"}
    $arrColumns = @($colAttribute, $colValue, $colDate)
    ForEach ($objColumn in $arrColumns) {$objDataGrid.Columns.Add($objColumn)}
}
```

However, I if I try and add a style through Powershell I come up against Dependency Properties. I've tried to examine them by creating the style in XAML and then trying to reverse engineer it in Powershell, this is what I've worked out so far:

$dataGridUser.Columns[0].ElementStyle is Type System.Windows.Style
$dataGridUser.Columns[0].ElementStyle.Triggers is Type System.Windows.Trigger
$dataGridUser.Columns[0].ElementStyle.Triggers.Property is Type Selected.System.Windows.Trigger
$dataGridUser.Columns[0].ElementStyle.Triggers.Property.Property is Type System.Windows.DependencyProperty

I'm unable to create an object of type System.Windows.DependencyProperty which should hold a Name property of Text. The best I have managed so far is to create one column through XAML and then extract the Dependency property object like this:

```
$objDepend = $($dataGridUser.Columns[0].ElementStyle.Triggers | Select Property).Property
```

Using this object, I can then create a new column object with the correct trigger property  (I appreciate this is still missing the 'Setter' property but I think the same principles will apply) like this:

```
$objSelect = $(New-Object System.Windows.Trigger | Select Property)
$objSelect.Property = $objDepend
$objTrigger = New-Object System.Windows.Trigger 
$objTrigger.Value = ""
$objTrigger.Property = $objSelect.Property
$objStyle = New-Object System.Windows.Style
$objStyle.Triggers.Add($objTrigger)
$colAttribute = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn -Property @{"Header" = "Attribute"; "Binding" = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding "Attribute"; "ElementStyle" = $objStyle}
```

This is clearly not the right way to go about this though, I am obviously missing something, presumably around Dependency properties which I suspect of being derived rather than simply set.

I hope that all makes sense, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is acceptable to answer my own (and only) question but I thought I would share the solution I developed in case anyone else is in a similar position.

Simply write a function that creates the Windows.Style.Object and passes it back. I've started with two default strings like so:

```
$strXAMLStart = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridTrigger">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>`n
"@

$strXAMLEnd = @"
                           </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
```

So the function briefly creates and loads an XAML object using the style parameters passed to it and then extracts the style object and passes it back as the result of the function. This can then be applied to the column in the UI.
The function is as follows:

```
Function Set-ColumnStyle ($hashStyle)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
    Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $strXAMLTrigger = $null
    ForEach ($key in $hashStyle.Keys)
    {
        $strValue = $hashStyle[$key]
        If ($key -eq "Blank") {$strTrigger = ""}
        Else {$strTrigger = $key}
        $strXAMLTrigger += "                                <Trigger Property=`"Text`" Value=`"$strTrigger`">`n"
        $strXAMLTrigger += "                                    <Setter Property=`"Background`" Value=`"$strValue`"/>`n"
        $strXAMLTrigger += "                                </Trigger>`n"
    }

    [xml]$xamlContent = $strXAMLStart + $strXAMLTrigger + $strXAMLEnd

    $xamlReader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xamlContent)
    $xamlWindow = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader)
    $dataGridTrigger = $xamlWindow.FindName("dataGridTrigger")
    $objStyle = $dataGridTrigger.Columns[0].ElementStyle

    Return $objStyle
}
```

I've used the string "blank" to represent actual blank cells, so this is replaced by "" if detected.
You can now call this function and pass it a hashtable of column contents to desired colours and use the returned object to set the style on the column:

```
$hashStyle = @{"Blank" = "#FFFF5050"; "0" = "#FF50FF50"; "267009" = "#FF50FF50"}
$objStyle = Set-ColumnStyle $hashStyle
$colDay = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn -Property @{"Header" = "Day"; "Binding" = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding "Day"; "ElementStyle" = $objStyle}
$dataGridScripts.Columns.Add($colDay)
```

Hope that all makes sense!