# WPF and powershell, need to know how to add style to a control element

Tags: wpf, powershell, templates, formatting

I am having some trouble setting the style to a groupbox control element.

I have some XAML code that has styling defined at the top of the code.  i am looking for a way to add the styling already defined to an element that i am creating dynamically.

Here is my styling section:

```
<Window.Resources> 
        <Style x:Key="GroupBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="8" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                              Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

This is what i have for my element creation:

```
   $NewBox = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox
   $NewBox.Content = "L " + $counter 
   $NewBox.Header = "t"
   $NewBox.Margin = "0"
   $NewBox.Style = "GroupBoxStyle1"
   $NewBox.Name = "FirstBox"
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($NewBox,1)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($NewBox,1)
```

I used the style property since that was what i could find using the 'Get-Member' command.  i have a feeling i am not using the right syntax to call the target type.  Because while i can get the groupbox to appear, i continually get the following error:

Exception setting 'Style':  "Cannot convert the 'GroupBoxStyle1 value of type "System.String" to type "System.Windows.Style"."

Comment: [May be related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24328412/5039142)

Comment: You should set the `Style` property to a `Style`. Something like `$NewBox.Style = $window.TryFindResource("GroupBoxStyle1")`.

Comment: @mm8 - That is what i needed, i was just stuck not understanding the syntax i needed.  now i can see all the garbage i put in trying to test the style.  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Style` property to a `Style`:

```
$NewBox.Style = $window.TryFindResource("GroupBoxStyle1")
```